# SQLite - return sorted list

Tags: sqlite

I can use

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id IN (478,278,190,890,123)
```

to return a list of records.

How can I instruct SQLite to return the records sorted using the order as specified in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no dedicated instruction to such thing.
You have to find a solution for each case.

In your example, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE id IN (478,278,190,890,123)
 ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 478 THEN 0
                  WHEN 278 THEN 1
                  WHEN 190 THEN 2
                  WHEN 890 THEN 3
                  WHEN 123 THEN 4
          END
```

But if you have a long list of ids, it will become difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. Best answer so far. Yes, if the list is long then the query will be huge. Let's see if somebody else could come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: The order of these ids comes from where? Is it always the same? i.e.: for example 478 is always before 278 in all of your queries.

Comment: At the moment the order of the ids comes from a config file (which will probably be changed once a week), but eventually it will come from a user selection. I'm probably better off sorting the rows in the application. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, in your case it's better to do the sorting in the application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use order by the field name. In this I am assuming id 
`select * from table where id in (478,278,190,890,123) order by id`

Comment: No. "order by id" would give me 123,190,278,478,890. I want the order to be 478,278,190,890,123.

Comment: you can use `order by id DESC`